# Trigger AWS lambda from Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to both aws lambda and Postgres .
So i wanted to ask can we trigger AWS lambda from Postgres manually?
Is there any way?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by triggering from Postgres?

Comment: I wonder whether [PL/Python - Python Procedural Language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpython.html) would allow use of the AWS SDK (boto3) to call AWS Lambda?